# Regex - for comma seperated multiple values

Tags: regex

I am new to regex / regular expressions.

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to apply regex on an input field.
where 5 digits **alphanumeric** are allowed.

and if user wants to add multiple values they must be **comma (,)** separated.

So for single value:

> k39Ka

For multiple value:

> Kha93,0Lk3i,L9kHK

so far I am able to achieve this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{5},)+
```

Comment: What language are you using? Please update the question tags with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]{5})*$
```

This should do it for you.Use `^$` to disallow partial matches.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/6